# mail:inbound-channel-adapter correct format of imap in store-uri

Tags: imap, spring-integration

Hello I have problem with setting up imap correctly. It worked for me with gmail but not with my custom mailbox.

This is how I have it set in mail app on my computer

http://partika.sk/help.png

this is my code

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter   id="customAdapter"
                                    store-uri="imaps://contact%64diversityweb.sk:<password>@imap.websupport.sk:993/inbox"
                                    channel="inputMail"
                                    should-delete-messages="false"
                                    should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
                                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should try to avoid linking to external sites and rather add the information in your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any special characters in your password, they need to be escaped (like you escaped @ to %64 in the user name).

However, `@` should be `%40` (hex), not `%64` (decimal). `%64` is `d`.

Set `mail.debug` to `true` in your javaMailProperties to get a bunch of debug information on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If your username contains the @ character use %40 instead of @ to avoid parsing errors from the underlying JavaMail API.